# Marshalling.getProvidedMarshallerFactory("serial") throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, jboss

Here is my code and error:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Marshalling.getProvidedMarshallerFactory("serial");
}
```

}

[image: This is the error]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please convert your image into text.

Comment: A marshalling exception is mostly a sign of incompatibility between developers code and some provided code from server.